# Why Symfony doesn't have default URL mapping?

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks, routes

I'm starting out with Symfony2, I have some experience with Codeigniter and Zend. My question is why in Symfony there is no default route mapping like /(module)/controller/action -> to a class/method like other frameworks? as far as I know in Symfony we have to define a new route in an external config file like routing.yml in order to make it work. What is the reason/benefits of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It forces you to turn on your brain when defining the URL layout.

By using automatisms such as using module/controller names (other frameworks) or file names (plain php) you are likely to get ugly urls or choose bad controller names to keep the urls nice.